# fatal error: dht11.h: No such file or directory

Tags: pi-3, c, servo

I have written the following code:

```
// wiring schema:
// DHT11 --> Raspberry Pi
// PIR --> Raspberry Pi 
// Servo Motor --> Raspberry Pi 

#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <wiringPi.h> 
#include <softPwm.h> 
#include <dht11.h> 

// Set up constants 
#define DHT11_PIN 0 
#define PIR_PIN 1 
#define SERVO_PIN 2 

int main(void) 
{ 
// Initialize the wiringPi library 
if (wiringPiSetup() == -1) { 
    printf("wiringPi setup failed!\n"); 
    exit(1); 
} 

// Set up the PIR 
pinMode(PIR_PIN, INPUT); 

// Set up the servo motor 
pinMode(SERVO_PIN, OUTPUT); 
softPwmCreate(SERVO_PIN, 0, 200); 

// Set up the DHT11 
dht11 DHT11; 

while (1) { 
    // Get temperature from DHT11 
    int result = dht11_read_val(&DHT11); 
    if (result != DHT11_OK) { 
        printf("Error reading DHT11 sensor\n"); 
        exit(1); 
    } 
// Get PIR signal 
    int pir_val = digitalRead(PIR_PIN); 

    // Move servo motor if both conditions are met 
    if (DHT11.temperature > 80 && pir_val == 1) { 
        softPwmWrite(SERVO_PIN, 10); 
        delay(1000); 
        softPwmWrite(SERVO_PIN, 0); 
        delay(1000); 
    } 

    // Delay for 1 second 
    delay(1000); 
} 

return 0; 
}
```

When I attempt to compile it on my Raspberry Pi it keeps returning "fatal error: dht11.h: No such file or directory". I know this means I have no directory named dht11.h, but I am unsure on how to install it - or more, if I can even install it on a Raspberry Pi (as I believe this is for Arduino?). Any help in fixing the code to run on a raspberry pi would be greatly appreciated.

Currently I am looking at the adafruit dht11 library but I believe its implementation in the code is different, and I do not want to rewrite too much of my code as this was intended as a simple side project.

To explain the code, it attempts to move a servo motor 90 degrees if the PIR sensor detects motion and if the DHT11 sensor detects a temperature higher than 80 degrees Fahrenheit. I will adjust the values more once I can get this working.

Comment: Arduino code does not work on the Pi.  Arduino is sort of C++ with a purpose built framework.  Forget the Arduino and look for Pi (or Linux) solutions.  Unless you are familiar with C you might as well look at Python solutions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930250/raspberry-pi-arduino-libraries-folder

Comment: The OP's accepted answer seems to be "I guess I'll just switch over to my Arduino" which makes this off topic and not useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to use this device directly from a Raspberry Pi GPIO connection?  Or are you "piggybacking" from an Arduino to a Raspberry Pi?

It looks like you are utilizing the Arduino C code and this will not work unless it's flashed onto an Arduino based microcontroller hosting the sensor.

This code would be localized to function on the Arduino. I don't see any means to that data being sent or 'traversed' to say, your Raspberry Pi.  But if Arduino alone does the trick, then no need for Raspberry Pi.
(UNLESS YOU ARE USING ARDUINO IDE ON RASPBERRY PI AS A COMPUTER TO FLASH THE CODE!)

One great ide/tool I would recommend if you are sticking with the Raspberry Pi only is either stick with a python based script, OR even better:  Node-Red.

Node-Red usually comes with Raspbian installation, and is super easy to install.  It was geared around IoT development and makes working with many sensors (and other neato stuff) quite easy.

Installation script can be found in the Node-Red.org documentations:
https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/raspberrypi

If you pairing this with an Arduino, you can do a Serial.println(x) of your data,
This will send that data out on the Serial bus line,
and with the Arduino connected to the Raspberry Pi via USB, and a script (or node-red Serial In node) that can read the serial input from the Arduino, and parse the data.

Node-Red would cover all these bases without having to use Arduino, and I have used the DHT11 sensor (though it's not as accurate as other sensors).
Just plug the Pins to 5v and Ground on the Pi and the data pin to an appropriate GPIO pin on the Pi.  See a Raspberry Pi GPIO pin diagram to help you determine what pin does what.

One problem as of late is the Raspberry Pi's are way up in price.  Seems to be a trend lately the past 2 years.  Sticking to cheaper Arduino is wise, but very well could have it's limitations.

Further:

Install the DHT11 sensor from the node-red pallet manager, and you can bring this to your "flows" and adjust the settings within the node (double clicking)

Node-Red is definitely worth the time to learn, and it's a web based IDE.

---

This was linked from :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930250/raspberry-pi-arduino-libraries-folder

```
you can add your libraries in

/usr/share/arduino/libraries/
then just include them with the include statement

#include <myAwesomeLib.h>
```

So obtain and copy the DHT11 library folder into this directory, and Arduino IDE should scan it and reference it next compile.

Comment: I'm working with a raspberry pi, so I guess I'll just switch over to my Arduino, like you said it seems simpler that way.

Comment: How are you flashing the Arduino?  Raspberry Pi Arduino IDE?  Another computer?
Simplicity would be using Node-Red if you are sticking with Raspberry Pi.
But that comes with installation and a learning curve if you never used it before.